# How can I know if the mail received is a parent mail using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to delete all replies and forwards to a mailbox.

I **already have disabled the Reply, Reply To All and Forward** from my master email template, but some people is using old mails to avoid creating a new one.

I am also **checking the email subject for the strings "RE:" and "FWD:"** to treat them as I want, **but some people change the subject and I don't know how check if it's a original mail (parent mail)**.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: I'm not sure that Outlook can group them if they have different subjects. When they do have the same subject, though, you might consider looking into the Conversation object. Namely, the ConversationID
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/managing-outlook-items-as-conversations